# Injection "Symbol()" not found error Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, primevue

I am using confirmdialog in primevue and get this error:

> [Vue warn]: injection "Symbol()" not found

I have no idea what this error is and how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?
Here is my source code

```
const deleteCategory = () => {
        confirm.require({
            message: 'Are you sure you want to proceed?',
            header: 'Confirmation',
            icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
            accept: () => {
               notification.showMessage("Successfully!");
            },
            reject: () => {
              router.push({ name: "CategoriesPage" });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: maybe your mistake is `confirm.require({`

Answer (score 9):

The error `[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol()" not found` isn't related to the code you provided. `[Vue warn]: injection ... not found` can be reproduced when using `inject: ['injectedVar']` in a nested component without actually providing it from a parent.

So you should check what you trying to inject and where it needs to provided from. See the docs for more information: [Provide / inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html)